# magento 1.7.0.2 can not reindex product price

Tags: magento-1.7

I can not reindex Product Price, please help me
  Zend_Db_Statement_Exception Object
    (
        [_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
        [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
        [string:Exception:private] => exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in  /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
    Stack trace:
    #0  /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
    #1  /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #2  /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #3  /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #4  /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
    #5  /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO`ca...', Array)
    #6  /public_html/app/code/local/Innoexts/StorePricing/Model/Mysql4/Downloadable/Indexer/Price.php(125): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
    #7  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Resource/Indexer/Price.php(47): Innoexts_StorePricing_Model_Mysql4_Downloadable_Indexer_Price->_prepareFinalPriceData()
    #8  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
    #9  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
    #10  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
    #11  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
    #12  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(178): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
    #13  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->massReindexAction()
    #14  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massReindex')
    #15  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #16  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #17  /public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #18  /public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #19 {main}

Comment: Please help me solve this problem

Comment: have you recently run an update on the store?

Comment: have you add any column in product?